# python Set method is ordered but not working Why?

Tags: python, set

My Python code:

```
ls1=[2,3,6,6,4]
v=set(ls1)
print(v)               # o/p : set([2, 3, 4, 6])

ls3=[9,13,14,7,6,5]
z=set(ls3)
print(z)               # o/p : set([5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 14])
```

but in this case its not going to work !

```
ls2=[8,7,6,5,4]
q=set(ls2)
print(q)               # o/p : set([8, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

why??

Comment: sets are unordered. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=set#sets

Comment: ls=[8,7,6,5,4,4] -> v=set(ls) -> also not working

Comment: `set` is not a method, it is a type-constructor, and `set` objects are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 0):

A Set is an unordered collection data type that is iterable, mutable, and has no duplicate elements. Python’s set class represents the mathematical notion of a set. The major advantage of using a set, as opposed to a list, is that it has a highly optimized method for checking whether a specific element is contained in the set. This is based on a data structure known as a hash table.

[Sets in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-python/)